# Unbind Space in normal mode

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I set my mapleader to Space as `:let mapleader = "\<Space>"` and use it in command mode quite often. But when I hold it it makes the cursor to move forward which is very annoying.

***QUESTION:*** Is there a way to unbind Space in normal mode?

Comment: I also have my leader set to space, I think you might want to add this line in your `.vimrc` so you can keep your leader in normal mode and Vim will wait before moving your cursor: `set notimeout ttimeout ttimeoutlen=200`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
nnoremap <Space> <NOP>
```

I also use `Space` as my leader, it does not seem to conflict.